# Android Cast String name to R.drawable.name

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Inside my android application, I need to create a function inside a class `MyAdapter` which is used inside the Activity `MyActivity` (which is not the `MainActivity`). The function should have the following structure

```
public int getDrawableResourceId(String name) {
    // naive explanation
    return R.drawable. + name
}
```

For example if I call `getDrawableResorceId("test")` it should return the integer value of `R.drawable.test`. I cannot work with `int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());` because Android Studio tells me that cannot resolve the methods `getResources()` and `getPackageName()`. If I replace it with

```
int drawableResourceId = MyActivity.this
                                   .getResources()
                                   .getIdentifier(name, "drawable", MyActivity.this.getPackageName());
```

or

```
int drawableResourceId = MainActivity.this
                                     .getResources()
                                     .getIdentifier(name, "drawable", MainActivity.this.getPackageName());
```

Android Studio tells me that the Activity is not an enclosing class. That is why I directly want to cast the String into `R.drawable.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I edited my answer, got the wrong question in mind:

```
public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name) {
   return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Update *

Since you are in an Adapter let's say you have MyAdapter as class name do:

```
public class MyAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }
....
```

Then below you can easily call:

```
getDrawable(mContext, "name")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I get the context?

Comment: So if you for example you are using the getDrawable function inside your MainActivity, you can simply use ```this``` or MainActivity.this e.g. getDrawable(this, "name") if you are in Fragment you can use getActivity()

Comment: If I replace context in the function with getActivity() it still cannot resolve the method. I think this is because I am inside the Adapter and not inside an activity.

Comment: so calling your MyAdapter would be like new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this) or MyAdapter(getActivity()).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your patience :D. I had to use `MyAdapter(MyActivity.this)` and it worked like a charm ;-).